# Создание формы на основе main.cpp в Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qtcreator, qt, form, форма

Есть код в `main.cpp`, который описывает форму программы. Я создал форму

```
mainwindow.ui (Add new->Qt Designer Form->Main Window).
```

Мне необходимо на основе этого "импортировать" в форму описанные объекты.

```
QMainWindow mainWindow; // окно программы
Field field; // игровое поле
QMenuBar *menuBar; // меню
QLabel *label;

mainWindow.setCentralWidget(&field);
menuBar = mainWindow.menuBar();

QAction *newAct = new QAction(QObject::tr("&New game"), &mainWindow);
QObject::connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), &field, SLOT(on_gameReset()));
menuBar->addAction(newAct);

mainWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего используется опция "Designer Form Class", которая добавляет не только форму, но и класс виджета, в котором автоматически инициализируется эта форма. Если же хочется сделать форму без наследования от `QMainWindow`, это можно сделать так:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  //MainWindow w;
  QMainWindow mainWindow;
  Ui::MainWindow mainWindowUi;
  mainWindowUi.setupUi(&mainWindow);
  mainWindow.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```